# How to publish several SharePoint lists to a one single document?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, document

I am looking for an advice on how to publish several SharePoint lists to one document which will be published based on item created.

**Example**:

I have following lists:

1. Proposal --> Description, Start date, End date
2. Case --> Scope, Employee name
3. Report --> Publish date, Actions completed

Each contains several information which I would like to publish in a single document (word document).
I am able to publish one list to one document using quick parts linked to a particular list.

How would I achieve to display all the above mentioned lists in one word document? Also, I have limited rights to link the document in any database queries.

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe this is possible. You could however consider using Excel and from there link to several lists in SharePoint. You can then use standard Excel features to manipulate and display the data from the different lists :)

[image]